# When my loop repeats, why isn't the random value assigned to a certain variable changing?

Tags: java

```
    System.out.println("Composition Statistics for Families with Two Children: \n");
    System.out.println("Total Number of Families: ");
    FamilyNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(boy, girl);
    
    while (RunCount < FamilyNumber) {
        
        randNum = (int)(Math.random() * 1 + 0);
        randNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 1 + 0);
        FirstGender = list.get(randNum);
        SecondGender = list.get(randNum2);
        
        GenderValues = FirstGender + SecondGender;
        
        if (GenderValues == "BG" || GenderValues == "GB") {
            BGCount++;
        }
        else if (GenderValues == "GG") {
            GGCount ++;
        }
        else {
            BBCount++;
        }
        
        RunCount++;
    
        
    }
    
    GGPercent = ((double)(GGCount/FamilyNumber)*(100)); 
    BGPercent = ((double)(BGCount/FamilyNumber)*(100));
    BBPercent = ((double)(BBCount/FamilyNumber)*(100));
    
    System.out.println("Number of Families with: \n");
    System.out.println("\tTwo Boys: " + BBCount + " Represents " + BBPercent + "%");
    System.out.println("\tTwo Girls: " + GGCount + " Represents " + GGPercent + "%");
    System.out.println("\tOne Boy and One Girl: " + BGCount + " Represents " + BGPercent + "%");
```

This is the segment of code the issue is in. I already initialized all the variables and imported everything necessary. The problem is, whenever I run the program, I get this output:

```
Composition Statistics for Families with Two Children: 

Total Number of Families: 
15
Number of Families with: 

    Two Boys: 15 Represents 100.0%
    Two Girls: 0 Represents 0.0%
    One Boy and One Girl: 0 Represents 0.0%
```

The output is always two boys make up all the families. I'm assuming that the issue is with randNum and randNum2 variables, but I'm really not sure. I have no idea what to do so any input on where I'm going wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do not compare strings with `==`. Ever. Use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with an upper case letter; variables and methods start with lower case letters.

Answer (score 2):

Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1.
So when cast to an int it will be always 0.
Select a scaling factor and multiply the result (lets say 5)
and then the result will an int in the range 0-4

Comment: Or call `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(2)` or `TreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean() ? 1 : 0`